# Laravel: Ignore 412 error page

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

There's must be a very simple solution to this but I had no idea how to search for this in Google or Stackoverflow for that matter so, yeah, I did not find anything so far.

I've written a simple API route in Lumen that returns a json string containing 421 on validation fail:

```
 {   "code": 412,   "status": "error",   "data": "validation failed" }
```

Now I wanted to call that route in another Laravel project, but then instead of the JSON string from the API I get an enormous **error** page saying:

> Client error: `POST
>   http://www.serellyn.net/development/game_api/public/platforms`

resulted in a `412 Precondition Failed` **response:**

```
{"code":412,"status":"error","data":"validation failed"}
```

I do think this is pretty normal behaviour since Laravel is seeing a error on its response. But all I want to do is receive my own json string with the 412 error code and be able to continue using my webpage.

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.

Edit: Forgot to add some code. I use Guzzle to call my API.

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://www.serellyn.net/development/game_api/public/', 'auth' => array('dev', '<dev>2016')]);
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'platforms', array('form_params' => ['name' => $request->name]));
        if($res->getStatusCode() == 201) {
            Session::flash('success', $request->name . ' successfully added');
        } else {

        }
        return redirect()->route('platforms.add.get');
```

Comment: can you post the code that you use to call the api ?

Comment: @AmirBar, sorry about that. I wanted to add it in the first place, I forgot to :)

Comment: @AmirBar Check my edit :)

Comment: take a look at the docs under Exceptions http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#exceptions "A GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException is thrown for 400 level errors if the http_errors request option is set to true"

Comment: so the final answer is:  $res = $client->request('POST', 'platforms', array('http_errors' => false,'form_params' => ['name' => $request->name]));
        if($res->getStatusCode() == 201) {

Comment: Great @AmirBar thank you. Can you place your comment as an answer? Then I can accept it and you get your points :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the response is correct. What I would do is catch the error in the try-catch block and then continue how I would like.

Comment: But then I can't use what I return in my JSON, right? Because the API does the validation, so if the validation fails I would like to know which validation fails and that is handled in my API and then returned in the JSON.

Comment: Sure you can. You should send the error message along with the error. In try-catch get the error message from the Exception and you can find out what failed.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that Guzzle thrown exception for 400 level errors if the http_errors request option is set to true. (which is the default value)

you need to put `'http_errors' => false` in the request like:

```
$client->request('POST', 'platforms', array('http_errors' => false,'form_params' => ['name' => $request->name])); if($res->getStatusCode() == 201) {
```

[http_errors docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#http-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue but with a website and I simply rewrote my mod_security module on the apache server, and it worked well with ssl again. You can read more [here](https://www.eukhost.com/kb/412-precondition-failed-error-solved/)